# How can I automatically generate an Xorg.config file?

Tags: installation, mouse, arch-linux

I'm trying to install arch linux, and everything has been going well so far, up until I start to install X.

It detects my dual monitors appropriately and will display windows, however, X will not recognize my USB mouse.

Is there any advice on how to setup a USB mouse for use in Xorg.config files?

I currently have the HAL daemon installed.

Answer (score 3):

```
X -configure
```

that will create an initial Xorg.conf :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried starting X without a config file. I did this for the first time while installing Arch on my EeePC 701 the other day. After ensuring all the drivers for the video card and input devices were installed, I started xfce4 without an `Xorg.conf` and everything worked perfectly. I can even hot plug external monitors with ease.

Comment: I tried to use startx and it displayed properly, but still no mouse recognition.

Comment: @samoz Just to make sure, you do have http://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/i686/xf86-input-mouse/ installed, right?

Comment: Yes I installed that

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure all the requiered xf86-- packages that you need is installed.
And that dbus and hal is started

Then you can delete your xorg.conf file and all should work